# Are Python sockets suitable for file synchronization?

Tags: python, networking, sockets, file-storage

I'm working in an organisation with limited funds. They can't afford a business account on [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/home). However, they would find it useful to have all their files synchronized on local machines.

I've recently looked at [Python Sockets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) and it looks as though a custom script could achieve what they're looking for. I'm concerned that it may be too low-level  because a library may exist that provides a lot of functionality and it would be a waste of resources to start from scratch.

Is there a Python library/module that would provide what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like you would be reimplementing `rsync` in Python. If you're mainly synchronizing NIX machines you should talk a look at using that. Specifically for Python, libraries like `fabric` can help you push files to remote machines.

Comment: The desktop machines that are in the office run Windows.

Comment: There are lots of other tools that can do it for you like rsync and btsync(also available as mobile version) etc.I Personally would not choose implementing my own file sync tool unless there is something very important that I need and these tools do not provide.

Comment: rsync is available for windows.  You can also check out robocopy, which is a little like rsync, but I believe it comes with windows.